# Changing the position and styling of particular label or button for a particular template in mediawiki?

Tags: css, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I have an ApprovedRevs extension on my wiki and i want to change its position and color for a particular template. Currently, it is shown as a subtitle alongside the Title. I also want to convert it in a blue tick sign rather than an approved label.

Can anyone tell me which files should i affect and how should i do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically **ApprovedRevs** use [DisplayOldSubtitle](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/DisplayOldSubtitle) hook to alter/add to original page subtitle, you may find a callback body at `setSubtitle` function in `ApprovedRevs.hooks.php` file.

However in your case just modifying this code would not be enough - since you've mentioned that you need to alter styles and position only for pages which contain particular template.

Depending on your exact needs you can:

1. Either disable display of subtitle bundled with ApprovedRevs by removing a callback and implement own parser-function extension providing you with a custom parser-function like `{{#approval_status:}}` to fetch & display current state approval status with any custom styles you want - this way you can call this function somewhere in template so it'll not be run for other pages.
2. Or you can go with a workaround which is limited in terms of changing subtitle position but should allow you to use own styles only for particular template based pages: modify your skin to add page categories as classes for `body` or `html` tag, eg.: for pages with Category `Company` it'll become `<body class="category-company category-something">`, then add a category to your template and after that you should be able to use this custom selector for styling based on page template via modifying `Common.css` page.

Comment: can you share some resources where i can get some knowledge about adding classes to the body tag for a particular template?